# Python Pandas Conditional Operation on entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, I don't want to change an original, I want to copy it and conditionally change it in a for loop, my df look like this:

```
         7267         9341    1759
7267     0.0          1.0      0.0
9341     1.0          0.0      1.0
1759     1.0          1.0      0.0
```

I want to write code that looks something like this:

```
for i in range(2):
    df_copy = df.copy()
    df_copy= df_copy.astype(int)
    df_copy.loc[df == i] = 1
    df_copy.loc[df != i] = 0
```

where the first pass through the for loop df_copy returns:

```
         7267         9341    1759
7267      1            0        1
9341      0            1        0
1759      0            0        1
```

and the second pass through returns:

```
         7267         9341    1759
7267      0            1        0
9341      1            0        1
1759      1            1        0
```

Comment: Just `df_copy = df.eq(i).astype(int)`.

Comment: the code in the question doesn't make much sense. First, at least with `pandas=1.2.3`, it raises `KeyError` because `[df == i]` is not a proper indexing. Second, what is the point of all iterations except the last value of `i`?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, I am puzzled by the intent and code in the original question.

First, at least with `pandas=1.2.3`, it raises `KeyError` because `df == i` (a DataFrame) cannot be used as argument for a `.loc[]` indexing. (It could, however, be used as direct indexing, e.g. `df_copy[df == i] = 1`).

Second, what is the point of all iterations except the last value of `i`?

The following works:

```py
imax = 1
df_copy = df.eq(imax).astype(int)
```